# How is Spring Batch commit count in batch_step_execution metadata table calculated

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I was attempting to do some validation on my Spring Batch application, which consists of 1 job and 1 step (TaskletStep) that has a reader/processor/writer.

Now, I noticed while validating the read/write counts from the execution metadata tables in database, the commit count each time seemed incorrect, or rather my understanding is lacking. For example, I have a simple CSV file that I read that has 10 rows in it. I set my chunk size to 3. Now, per the image below and as I understand, the Framework will read  each row via the **ITEM READER** in the CSV and pass it to the **ITEM Processor**, and then continue to the next item to be read UNTIL the chunk size is met. Thus, the sequence should be as follows per my dummy example:

1. item1 is read, passed to processor (chunk size NOT met yet, 1/3)
2. item2 is read, then passed to processor (chunk size NOT met yet, 2/3)
3. item3 is read, then passed to processor (chunk size IS met yet, 3/3)
4. Chunk size of 3 requirement is met, so the entire Chunk is
   passed to Writer and then should count as **1 COMMIT** (wrapped in one transaction).

[image]

I have this exact setup locally, and for some reason, I keep getting a `commit_count` in the batch_step_execution metadata table in database as **5**. Now, this doesn't make sense to me as, 10 is divisible by 3 only 3 times, and thus the remainder, or item10 (the one last item), would be the last transaction committed for a total commit count of **4**.

Am I missing something here? I would like to make sure I understand this framework thoroughly, thanks.

Comment: And an additional 1 to update the final status of the batch job.

Comment: Can you post as answer so I can upvote you and give you best answer

Comment: +1 to what Marten said. I just want to add two clarifications regarding your diagram: 1. the transaction is not around the writer only, the transaction is around the reader/processor/writer. 2. An item is not passed to the processor right after being read, items are accumulated in a chunk before being passed to the processor/writer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be an additional commit to write the final step/job status.

So 4 for the chunks and an additional one for the final status change.

Comment: As per example, if step is failed there will be at one commit for final status which marked failed, but seems like it's not counting that one and value on commit_count is 0. Do any idea on that part?